# Exception while connecting to mail server

Tags: java, email, ssl, websphere, exchange-server

I got the following exception while connecting to Mail server from IBM WAS.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\jre\lib\security\cacerts (The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

My question is:

What is the certificate that I should import? Is it the mail server's certificate which needs to be imported into WAS? Should I ask the mail server admin to share the certificate?

Once I figure out which certificate, I plan to follow these instructions to import it:
[How to connect to a secure website using SSL in Java with a pkcs12 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537040/how-to-connect-to-a-secure-website-using-ssl-in-java-with-a-pkcs12-file)

Answer (score 1):

That link is not the correct way to use mail sessions in WAS. Check this [Websphere 7 javax.mail.MessagingException: SSLSocketFactory is null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24406804/3701228).

Try to use default SSL WebSphere configuration and Mail session resource. You will need to add your mail server certificate to the Trust store (`NodeDeaultTrustStore` or `CellDefaultTrustStore` depending whether you use standalone or network deployment version).

It should be possible to get mail server cert using a browser, when you connect using `https://mailserver:port`/ it should give you certificate which you could save locally and add to truststore. If you will have problems contact mail server admin.

`PrivilegedActionException` also suggest that you may have `Java 2 security` enabled. Check if it is enabled and if you really need it.